# Зачем sync_to_async?

Tags: python, django, asyncio, django-channels

```
class EchoConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        instance = await sync_to_async(Task.objects.last)()
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'name': instance.name}))
```

Почему нельзя просто написать instance = Task.objects.last() ?

Какие процессы скрываются за sync_to_async ?

Comment: Поясните, пожалуста, причем здесь `async_to_sync`, если в примере кода `sync_to_async`?

Comment: Полезные ссылки по теме: https://webdevblog.ru/asinhronnye-predstavleniya-v-django-3-1/, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/async/, https://habr.com/ru/post/461493/

Comment: @mrEvgenX перепутал, речь идет про sync_to_async